# WEB API 2.2 security with ajax call MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

we have two separate project 
1 - MVC 5 Application with knockoutJS and html5 which is presentation layer.
2 - Web API project with business layer , DAL.

we are going to host our application on two different IIS site. 
Presentation layer is hosted on windows authentication.
Now from our presentation we are making ajax call to Web API layer to GET, POST data.

I wanted to restrict Web API access direct from browser. for e.g. I have hosted Web API on port 8181.

If I enter direct URI on browser http://xxx:8181/api/value then it should not response any data back.

the Web API should be accessible by only Presentation layer only.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: You realise that an ajax call is simply a GET request right? That is exactly what your browser is doing when you enter it directly.

Comment: That what I don't want if I would hit direct API URI then it should not give me data back, because that API call is not from my presentation layer. I want to restrict it.

Comment: That's my point... if an AJAX call is no different, how do you expect to allow calls from AJAX and not from the browser?

Comment: You could include some custom header in your request that the browser wouldn't include. You can check on the server side whether this header is present. This would not be a "security" feature as any developer would be able to see what headers are being sent to the server and replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to lock down when and how methods in your WebAPI can be accessed, is by using CORS (Cross origin resource sharing).  If the MVC app is on a different port or domain from the Web API app, then CORS should apply.

Look for something in the web.config that might be allowing all origin domains, then you can specify what domain is allowed.

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://xxx:8181" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

You can also specify allowed domains and PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, etc. on specific methods in your WebAPI.  You can also write your own handler for CORS.

For more information on using CORS, see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api.